# \def with number in macro works?

Tags: macros, syntax

I know that numbers cannot be used in macros, e.g., in `\def`/`\newcommand` definitions. Can anybody explain to me why this

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\i2{\frac{i}{2}}

\begin{document}
$\i2$
\end{document}
```

works?

[image]

Comment: Try to type in `naïve` and see what happens.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the TeX book, page 202:

> TEX also allows you to define macros whose parameters are delimited in quite a general way; you needn’t always enclose arguments in braces. For example, `\def\cs #1. #2\par{...}` defines a control sequence `\cs` with two parameters, and its two arguments will be determined as follows: `#1` will consist of all tokens between `\cs` and the next subsequent
> appearance of ‘`.` ’ (period and space); `#2` will consist of all tokens between that ‘`.` ’ and the next `\par` token.

When you write

```
\def\i2{\frac{i}{2}}
```

you are *not* defining a macro <kbd>i2</kbd> (I use a keyboard symbol to denote a control sequence token) but rather a *delimited* macro <kbd>i</kbd> which *must* always be followed by the number 2 (spaces are gobbled after `\i` in the usual way). Therefore from

```
\def\i2{i/2}
\i2\par
\i 2\par
\i3
\bye
```

you'll get *i/2* twice, and an error

```
! Use of \i doesn't match its definition.
l.4 \i3
```

If you press `h` the help message says literally

```
If you say, e.g., `\def\a1{...}', then you must always
put `1' after `\a', since control sequence names are
made up of letters only. The macro here has not been
followed by the required stuff, so I'm ignoring it.
```

---

As egreg suggested, I add that using `\def` is *always* dangerous, because it does not check whether the macro is already defined. Simple example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\i2{\frac{i}{2}}
\begin{document}
Using \verb+\def+ is quite naïve\ldots
\end{document}
```

Running this code will also result in an error `Use of \i doesn't match its definition`. Why? The file `ot1enc.dfu` contains

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00EF}{\"\i}
```

(using a different font encoding works similarly), meaning that the Unicode character U+00EF (ï) is converted into `\"\i`, whose purpose is to put a dieresis `\"` onto a dotless i `\i`. But you've redefined `\i` to expect a 2 and to print a fraction! Chaos ensues.

Long story short: `\def`ining macros with delimited arguments can be *very* useful (I use them a lot in my packages) but you *really* have to know what you are doing...

---

The preceding discussion holds under normal `\catcode` regime. You could of course change the `\catcode`of `2` (or of all digits) from 12 (other) to 11 (letter) but, believe me, you don't want to do that...

You *can*  define a macro <kbd>i2</kbd> by something like

```
\expandafter\def\csname i2\endcsname{...}
```

but then of course you should write `\csname i2\endcsname` to use it...

Comment: I'd add the example of typing `naïve` that would also show why `\def` should be avoided.

Comment: @egreg Added `:-)`

Comment: Can't upvote twice, sorry.